# How do I get list of names from s txt file to display on the combo box?

Tags: java

I am stuck in a school project I have been working on. It's about getting all the info from the txt file I created and wanted to get the name of the products to the combo box and the rest of the products details shows on the numbers of the textbox.

The txt file content looks like this:

```
id|Category|Name|Price
0|Food|Pizza|$4.50
1|Drink|Pepsi|$2.10
```

and etc.

Here is my code i have been working on: (Sorry for not providing this earlier)

```
File product_file = new File("Product.txt");

Scanner scan = new Scanner(product_file);
scan.nextLine();//skip the column name/line
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scan.nextLine();//read each line
  String[] pieces = line.split("\\|");
  String product_name = pieces[2];
```

Not sure how to link it to the combobox.

Comment: Without any code provided, you will just get hints like "read all lines first, split them by | and then create an object out of the data"...

Comment: OK, but what is your question? Questions seeking debugging help ("I was stuck" ) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You talk about a "combo box" in your question. Is this relevant?

Comment: the combo box is for the user(customer) to select product so i want to use combo box as for them to choose the product with and shows details for the product selected by the user

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but if you want to read data in from a text file, try looking into the `Scanner` and `File` classes.

This would print the text file directly onto the screen, as it appears in your text file:

```
File file = new File("myTextFile.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
```

If you need to parse that data into different variables/objects, you can dump all the text into a big string and split it:

```
String str = "";
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    str += scan.nextLine();
}
String[] array = str.split("\\|");
```

For example, in your text file, `array[5]` will equal `"Food"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have extracted the `product_name` already, you just need to add it to your `ComboBox` items list:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();//read each line
    String[] pieces = line.split("\\|");
    String product_name = pieces[2];
    comboBox.getItems().add(product_name);
}
```